# High pings within online games even though command-line ping looks good

Tags: networking, router, openwrt

Since I started to use an LEDE router I've noticed more lag in minecraft.

I am using luci-app-sqm which may have something to do with it, ironically I installed the SQM QoS specifically to try to improve performance of online games.

Anyway, from the terminal pings to minecraft servers are consistent and low, e.g. `min/avg/max/stddev = 36.357/39.920/49.799/2.604 ms` — which is how they've always looked.

However, in-game my client tells me my pings (same server as above) are fluctuating from 200 ms up to sometimes 2000 ms. Here's one session: `min/avg/max/stddev = 159/336/781/182 ms`

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: QoS won't help an online game, it will prioritise 'more important' structures like video. You could simply be suffering server lag or even download/decode issues - but I'm not familiar enough with minecraft to better diagnose.

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought about server lag so tested on several servers I used to be able to play on smoothly before switching routers, but now all servers show the same inconsistent pings. What do you mean by download/decode issue?

Comment: If your machine is struggling to download data, decode it & render to screen, then it can cause queueing of data, which looks like high ping times [even though it's not really]

Comment: @Tetsujin oh interesting, I didn't know that was a thing. Is there a way I can test if that's the culprit?

Comment: It's hard for me to say without knowing the game at all; but general principles, have the computer trying to 'do less' - Lower your draw distance so you see less of your surroundings, lower things like antialiasing or anisotropic texturing if you have those controls.